# Trying to center align elements and divs inside a wrapper div

Tags: html, css, centering

```css
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box; /* This tells the chrome browser to use the tools for flexible boxes */
                  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                  -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: -moz-box;
                  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
                  -moz-box-flex: 1; 
    
    }
section {
         max-width: 760px; 
         margin-top: 20px;
         background-color: #121516;
         border-radius: 50px;
         padding: 10px;
         box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 10px #000;
         display: -webkit-box; /* This tells the chrome browser to use the tools for flexible boxes */
                  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
         display: -moz-box;
                  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
                  -moz-box-flex: 1; 
        order: 2;
        text-align: center;    
        }

aside  {      
         border-radius: 20px;
         margin-top: 15px;
         padding: 5px;
         color: #5F7278;
         width: auto;
         float: right;
         font-size: 85%;
         text-align: center;
         display: -webkit-box;
                  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
         display: -moz-box;
             -moz-box-orient: vertical;
             -moz-box-flex: 1;
         order: 3;
         position: absolute;
         }
 


#left-aside {
 display: -webkit-box;
             -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
             -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    display: -moz-box;
       -moz-box-orient: vertical;
       -moz-box-flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    max-width: 150px;
}
.box1  {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px;
    }

.box2   {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 25px;
    flex: 1;
}

.box3   {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 23px;
    flex: 1;
}

.box4 {
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 22px;
    flex: 1;
    }

.box4 a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.box5  {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    flex: 1;
    }
.box5 p {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.box5 form {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.box6  {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 660px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 40px;
    clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">  
   
      <div id="left-aside">
          Left aside
      </div>
   
      <section><!-- Main part of your page -->

    <h1>Main Section with two articles</h1>

     <article class="first"><!-- Informational section & can use multiple times -->
                          Article 1
      

     </article>

  <!-- Slideshow -->
 
  

   <article class="second"><!-- Informational section & can use multiple times -->
    
    Article 2
      


   </article>

   </section>


   <aside>
    
           Aside

     </aside> 
     
  </div>
```

I am trying to center align my elements and divs inside my wrapper div, I have tried:

```
text-align: center
margin: 0 auto
```

But none seem to appear to work as i am using the moz-box and webkit-box in my css, yet none of these center align the childs in the parent. I cannot for the life of me get this to work, I have also tried:

```
justify-content: center
align-items: center
```

Yet none of it center aligns in the parent it is stuck on the left side of the screen.

As a note, if i was to remove the:

```
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-box;
```

from the parents and child elements then i can easily align it all, however i will lose the responsiveness from the page and i am trying to make it as cross-platform friendly as possible.

Comment: can you post the relevant code snippet?

Comment: apologies i am a noob how would i upload a snippet?

Comment: In the edit / create question window, there's an icon to the right of the picture icon.  If you click that (the 7th from the left) you get a popup window/overlay where you can add sample code.

Comment: okay, do you just need the css?

Comment: try giving your wrapper a certain width say 70% for example and retry the margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Ideally an example of relevant html and the css that replicates the problem in a shortened form so that  we can see there's nothing else affecting it by the items you're looking at.  E.g. a few divs and the css that reflects the problem applied to those divs? if possible?

Comment: Okay, I have edited it now so it should appear easier to see the problem, I have left and right asides with the section in the middle, however it is not centering in the wrapper div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I previously marked the previous answer as correct, although it worked it gave the div 100% width over the remaining use of the wrapper div and was not completley responsive, which left alot of whitespace and was not really cross browser support. So to center it all perfectly in the wrapper div with responsiveness i had to input the following lines of code into the parent div.

```
display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
```

This aligned everything inside the parent perfectly, with full responsiveness.

Comment: solution that i posted is ok, resposnive of your site is something else, another question, another answer.

Comment: Yes it worked but it was not aligned to the center, your solution expanded the left div to fill the available whitespace, giving the appearance of pushing other elements over but if you have a keen eye you can see it did not centre everything, this solution does

Comment: Please edit this post to make it either a self-contained answer, or alternatively delete this post, and add a comment to the other answer explaining the small changes you needed to make  in-order for it to work in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box; /* This tells the chrome browser to use the tools for flexible boxes */
                  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                  -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: -moz-box;
                  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
                  -moz-box-flex: 1; 
    
    }
section {
         max-width: 760px; 
         margin-top: 20px;
         background-color: #121516;
         border-radius: 50px;
         padding: 10px;
         box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 10px #000;
         display: -webkit-box; /* This tells the chrome browser to use the tools for flexible boxes */
                  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
         display: -moz-box;
                  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
                  -moz-box-flex: 1; 
        order: 2;
        text-align: center;    
        }

aside  {      
         border-radius: 20px;
         margin-top: 15px;
         padding: 5px;
         color: #5F7278;
         width: auto;
         float: right;
         font-size: 85%;
         text-align: center;
         display: -webkit-box;
                  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
         display: -moz-box;
             -moz-box-orient: vertical;
             -moz-box-flex: 1;
         order: 3;
         position: absolute;
         }
 


#left-aside {
 display: -webkit-box;
             -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
             -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    display: -moz-box;
       -moz-box-orient: vertical;
       -moz-box-flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.box1  {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0px;
    }

.box2   {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 25px;
    flex: 1;
}

.box3   {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 23px;
    flex: 1;
}

.box4 {
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 22px;
    flex: 1;
    }

.box4 a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.box5  {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    flex: 1;
    }
.box5 p {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.box5 form {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.box6  {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 660px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #000 inset;
    line-height: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 40px;
    clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">  
   
      <div id="left-aside">
          Left aside
      </div>
   
      <section><!-- Main part of your page -->

    <h1>Main Section with two articles</h1>

     <article class="first"><!-- Informational section & can use multiple times -->
                          Article 1
      

     </article>

  <!-- Slideshow -->
 
  

   <article class="second"><!-- Informational section & can use multiple times -->
    
    Article 2
      


   </article>

   </section>


   <aside>
    
           Aside

     </aside> 
     
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you highlight the changes?

Comment: just add relative instead absolute, to aside class

Comment: aside  {      
         border-radius: 20px;
         margin-top: 15px;
         padding: 5px;
         color: #5F7278;
         width: auto;
         float: right;
         font-size: 85%;
         text-align: center;
         display: -webkit-box;
                  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
         display: -moz-box;
             -moz-box-orient: vertical;
             -moz-box-flex: 1;
         order: 3;
         position: relative;
         }

Comment: Doesnt display properly when i try that and it doesnt align all elements and divs to the center of the wrapper

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oczsxnc4/4/

Is this your, code, if not please update, then we wil help you :)

Comment: appears that the code snippet does not display correctly, that snippet/code aligns the aside element to the left-aside and main section but my issue is the left-aside, main section and aside do not center to the wrapper div

Comment: can you provide link of site, because on jsfidle and here, everything is ok, and centred.

Comment: current site that  is live is outdated, i am updating it offline i can zip you the files if you like?

Comment: okay how do i send the files to you, cant upload a zip on here and cant pm you

Comment: dropbox, filedrive, etc... then provide link

Comment: just uploading now https://www.dropbox.com/s/mil0df1z07lksw1/feargamers.co.uk.rar?dl=0

Comment: #left-aside {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

Try this, it will give 100% to your left aside, and main will go to center...

Comment: That works, had to create another div within that so img was not distorted, I knew it would be one simple thing.....

Comment: could you edit your answer correctly and ill accept it, thanks ive been pulling my hair out for days on this